# Hubs not receiving any messages when using MassTransit SignalR backplane

Tags: c#, signalr, masstransit

I'm trying to setup the MassTransit SignalR backplane support right now. I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/signalr/quickstart.html

Here is my MassTransit configuration in my Startup.cs (This is called from the `ConfigureServices` call):

```
    private void ConfigureMassTransit([NotNull] IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR().AddMassTransitBackplane();

        // creating the bus config
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            // Add this for each Hub you have
            x.AddSignalRHubConsumers<ChatHub>();
            x.AddSignalRHubConsumers<NotificationHub>();

            x.AddBus(provider =>
            {
                var dnsResolutionService = provider.GetService<IDnsResolutionService>();
                var logger = provider.GetService<IMainLogger>();

                return MassTransitBusFactory.CreateBus(dnsResolutionService, logger, cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddSignalRHubEndpoints<ChatHub>(provider);
                    cfg.AddSignalRHubEndpoints<NotificationHub>(provider);
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

For now, I'm trying this with the following hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : BaseHub, INotificationHub
{
    public NotificationHub([NotNull] ISessionService sessionService) 
        : base(sessionService)
    {
    }

    public async Task Test(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("NewNotification", "bla");
    }
}
```

And here is my calling code:

```
    public Task RaiseSignalREvent()
    {
        var protocols = new IHubProtocol[] { new JsonHubProtocol() };

        return _eventBus.Publish<All<NotificationHub>>(new
        {
            Messages = protocols.ToProtocolDictionary("Test", new object []{"blub"}),
        });
    }
```

The code is obviously just for testing as of now. When I run this and call `RaiseSignalREvent`, I would've expected the NotificationHub method to be hit, however, right now nothing happens.

Here are some considerations I thought about which might be a problem:

1. I might be misunderstanding how the "Messages" parameter in the publish is being assembled.
2. The config is wrong. I'm publishing this from a service which doesn't have all the startup code as displayed.
3. I'm not sure about how MassTransit works, but as of now, I have two Buses in the service the Startup.cs in detail is located in. There's the bus coming from the ConfigureMassTransit method, and another one which is created in a service I hooked up to DI which I generally use for working with MassTransit. So essentially, there are 2 buses in that service. Does this matter?

Can anyone help me nail down the problem I'm facing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure what you mean by "I have two buses configured", but that sounds bad. What you've pasted in your `ConfigureMassTransit` method looks fine and that's all you need. It might help if you share some more code for the other places you're registering a bus, it could possibly mess things up.

I haven't really used SignalR, but a really common thing people miss when first starting out is that *you must start the bus*. Somewhere in your code you need to call `Start()` on an `IBusControl` instance or nothing is going to work.

Check out https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#web-application for some samples.

Apologies if you're already doing this!